# Electronic (musical) keyboard, 6+ octaves, stereo output whose split divides across outputs?

Tags: music

I am essentially looking for a Yamaha PSR EW300, but stereo, and with a weird feature that may not exist. To be less vague, I want a keyboard that

- Has 6 or more octaves
- Can split anywhere along the keyboard
- *Most important*: once split, its left keys play out of one channel and right keys out the other.

I would like a solution more elegant than my current one, which is to have two keyboards. To be able to use some music app on my phone with the keyboard would be a bonus, as well as having a mod wheel. I would also be okay to find out that such a keyboard does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Not weird at all; who wants to schlep two keyboards?

The [Yamaha MOXF6](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/music_production/synthesizers/moxf/index.html#product-tabs) offers this feature in a seven-plus octave range. To configure it to [split between two ranges](https://www.yamahasynth.com/ask-a-question/split-keyboard-to-transmit-over-2-midi-channels-at-once):

Press [MASTER] to enter the Master Keyboard mode.
You can setup a program to transmit Out to your DAW

Press [JOB]
Press [F1] INIT
We will initialize a Master location - do not worry about the factory programs, they are simply example "placeholders". You can overwrite these without fear of losing anything important.
With the "All" option marked, press [ENTER] to execute.

An "Initialized Master" is created.
On this main screen, press [F2] MEMORY
Here you can link this Master with an internal MOXF program. (You don't mention if you want to use an internal sound so this will not matter, just want to point out that if you wanted to layer the external piano with an internal MOXF sound, you could by associating this Master program with a VOICE, a PERFORMANCE or a SONG/PATTERN Mixing setup!)

Press [F3] SWITCH
Set the ZONE SWITCH = ON
And set the ZONE/KNOB = ON

Press [EDIT]
Here you can NAME the Master setup something appropriate by changing the default Name "Initialized Master"
Press the Track [1](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/music_production/synthesizers/moxf/index.html#product-tabs) button to view the four possible ZONES. You will be using just the first two slots.
[F1] TRANS (transmit) will be selected.

Set ZONE 1 as follows:
Transmit Channel = 1
Internal Switch = Off
External Switch = On

Press [2](https://www.yamahasynth.com/ask-a-question/split-keyboard-to-transmit-over-2-midi-channels-at-once)
Set ZONE 2 as follows:
Transmit Channel = 2
Internal Switch = Off
External Switch = On

Move to [F2] NOTE
Here you can set your NOTE LIMITS for each ZONE, Low and High
Set ZONE 1 C-2 through B2
Set ZONE 2 C3 through G8

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for the use of the checkmark  (✅) below the arrowheads.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're wanting an arranger keyboard may I recommend the Tyros 5 (76-note version) which can split the arranger and keyboard functions into 6 - 8 different outputs. (Press "mixing console -> output" to access this complete output matrix menu.) You can split and send any section of the keyboard or arranger functions up to 6 mono or 3 stereo outputs (eg LH, RH, RH part 2, RH part 3, multi-pads, vocal harmonies, style bass, style drums, audio drums, whatever is needed).

I use the Tyros 5 this way in my facebook and YouTube live videos. It's a great tool to be able to separate the outputs and split the keyboard and separate the two hands, and even more so to send out separate arranger instruments and vocal harmonies.

Hope this helps.

Dr. Steve Kuban

PS: Here's an example: "Bridge Over Troubled Water."

https://youtu.be/fsrbZSERR-o

Here are the output assigns I used:

Output 1 & 2 (stereo): arranger instruments (bass, drums, guitars) plus left hand;
Output 3 & 4 (stereo): right hand (playing the live piano)
Output 5 & 6: live ALTO vocal harmony to 5 (using the built-in vocal harmonizer)
              live TENOR vocal harmony to 6 
(I like sending the vocals out on separate outputs, it gives the ability to adjust the vocal harmony blend as needed.)

While singing live on facebook or YouTube, at the same time I output and record these 6 outputs to separate tracks of a multitrack recorder (eg. Zoom R24 8-track recorder, or DAW via an audio interface with discrete outputs, eg a Saffire Pro24DSP which has 16 simultaneous inputs, that's what I use).